# How do I retry a revoked Celery task using AsyncResult

Tags: python, celery

I want to retry a previously revoked task using a AsyncResult object but I get an error saying that the task will be discarded as soon as I run the task

```
worker_1 | [2019-06-27 16:04:23,094: INFO/MainProcess] Discarding revoked task: ...
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#persistent-revokes) a list of revoked tasks is stored in memory by the worker and isn't cleared until the worker is restarted.

Is there another way I can cancel a running task instead of revoking it or can I somehow remove the task from the list of revoked task?

Comment: Why not simply create a new task with the same parameters? Will that not work?

Comment: It would, however, I would like to reuse the exact same task to easier track the history of it

Comment: It does not make any sense. It is the same as when you free a part of memory, and later want to bring it back. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to bring back the revoked task from "the dead".

What I recommend you do is:

1. Create a new task with the same args as the revoked one.
2. Use the `update_state()` on the task, and specify the metadata that you can use to relate two different tasks (the revoked one, and the new one). Something like `tsk.update_state(meta={"job-id": "babadeda123", "client-id": "skynet", "previous-task-id": "64fb925e-86cb-4d29-b4e5-33f41f8416cc"})` where the *64fb925e-86cb-4d29-b4e5-33f41f8416cc* is the ID of the revoked task.